# Text Popups on Kindle Devices?

Tags: adobe-indesign, epub

So, I've got a Fixed Layout ePub. It was created in InDesign and published using Aquafadas publishing tools. I'm trying to figure out how to do text popups or quick footnote referencing on Kindle/Amazon/non-epub devices. I don't care how to do it, just trying to find ANY way to do it.

I need to be able to test it on my office's Kindle/Kindle Fire. It doesn't need to be exactly like iOS's solution as seen in the picture, but some way to to have reference to footnotes in the back. (And if that solution is linking to pages in the back, I need a quick way to jump back to the page the user was on)

[image: iBooks Footnote]

Comment: Hi there! I don't think this is the best place to ask this. There is an [ebooks proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46400/ebooks), but it's not a site yet. Maybe you'll have better luck in  [SU](http://www.superuser.com). It's still quite specific, so perhaps contacting Aquafadas directly is your best option.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Was just on the phone with them yesterday, trying to figure out how to do it with or without their software. Still no dice either way. I'll leave this is, Graphic Design was the closest I could find on StackExchange, thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

The way ePub work is very similar to how older 90' websites used to work with the benefits of CSS. You can use basic functions of HTML and CSS if you want to keep it "safe" (eg. fully compatible with pretty much any eReader.) They don't work like websites from the 90' but what I mean is you need to keep it simple.

The only quick (but not fancy) solution I can think of is to add a hyperlinks (or some graphic with a url) next to your footnote that goes back to the original position of the reference footnote number in the text. It could look like some kind of "to the top of the page" button as on websites. One hyperlink on the number of the footnote, and one on the footnote going back to the original page.

To my knowledge, you can use some limited javascript in ePub 3 but it's still really weak and I don't think all eReaders have ePub 3 support. Someone or some research will be necessary confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at this lesson. They teach how to create pop-us for the kindle. 
https://www.lynda.com/InDesign-tutorials/Creating-Fixed-Layout-eBooks-Kindle/433941-2.html?srchtrk=index%3a5%0alinktypeid%3a2%0aq%3akindle%0apage%3a1%0as%3arelevance%0asa%3atrue%0aproducttypeid%3a2

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.